# How can I query special characters

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my query I need to pick up this up in a CASE statement

```
''
```

Is there a way I could pull those? obviously I can't go `"''"` or `''''`

Comment: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type boolean: "' '"

Comment: I think you perhapse need to be clearer about what you want to do.  It seems your asking how to specify `''` in a string but then in the comments it seems you're not using the case statement correctly.

Comment: Check this one.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/03818/1

Comment: you're correct I want to specify it in a string, keep in mind if I put IS NULL or something like that it will work, it's just when I try to specify those characters that I get this error.

Comment: You are obviously not describing your problem properly. Please show some more effort, you are wasting the time of the good people trying to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your second guess was close. Once the string is open `''` is the correct way to specify a quote. So your string would be `''''''`.

Edit:

```
SELECT CASE when my_field = '''''' then 'yes' else 'no' end from my_table;
```

Edit 2:

Based on your comment, are you sure that it has the value `''`.  It sounds like it is a `boolean` field. In which case it's value is null.  Do you mean something like:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN my_field IS NULL THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END FROM my_table;
```

Comment: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type boolean: "''"

Comment: You might want to try making it equal to something. I've added a more complete example.

Comment: It is, I just did not write a full example, what you wrote is what my query looks like thought I'm still getting that error :/ (I use an old version of Postgres if that helps)

Comment: Try looking at my second update, I think your question is incorrect.

Comment: It's not a boolean field, it's a varchar field and it's got '' to apparently represent NULLs but that seems to be a mistake on the developer's part cause these won't pull out when I type "IS NULL" it will pull out results that are actually not in that table. I'm just saying this to point out that the query seems to be fine apart from the way I'm trying to pull out those special characters :(

Comment: Then why (given the syntax I've given above in edit 1) would you be getting a error due to postgresql attempting to turn the string `''` into a `boolean`?  The error message is quite clear and specific.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ''' '''
```

Try the above one..